# Expose Passport.js user to Express-Handlebars layout in Node.js Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, express-handlebars

I have a Node.js application that uses Express, Express-Handlebars with layout, and Passport.

After a user successfully logs in, I would like that user’s information (such as first name) to appear in the top of each page (something like: “Hello foodave” or similar).

Being new to Node.js, I haven’t been able to figure out how to expose the req.user object to the layout used Express-Handlebars.
Passing it to the view via “res.render” doesn’t seem to make it available to the layout.

After users log in, passing req.user in every route will work.
Here is code from the route:

```
res.render('home', {user: req.user});
```

Here is code from the layout view:

```
<p>Hello {{user.email}}</p>
```

Is there a way to expose the user object to the layout view so it does not need to be passed as a parameter in every single route?

Comment: Please include all relevant code

Comment: I edited my question to include relevant code.